# Laptop windows 10 wont boot missing winload.exe

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd

Ok I updated from an HDD to an SSD. Windows told me I can't update my windows 10 build due to system reserved space. So I extended the system reserve space from 38mb to 350mb and then rebooted my computer and it now wont boot, nor go to recovery nor nothing. I am currently booted up using an external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You may have burned up the SSD. However, if you can confirm it is ok on another machine then ok.

First, make sure that you have the ability to boot to the SSD in your BIOS. Then install windows seven on it. Then use the upgrade utility to upgrade to Win10.

Just start over. That is the best advice anyone can give you. Start fresh and start clean. I use Break-Fix all the time. Fastest method unless you already know the problem.